# i would like to explore attributes as means for branding. How do I create/use my own attributes

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-attributes

In MVC, you can decorate a property with values that can be read out by the Html helpers. For example Html.LabelFor() reads out the display attribute of a property. What I am wondering, is it possible to do this for a complete value? I'm exploring the possibility of controlling branded information through the use of attributes. Here's what I envision:

```
[Branded]
public string Greeting { get; set; }
```

And then when this property is readout, the attribute will run and pull out the branded information through some other mechanism. I think the reason I headed down this path is that we need to be able to brand as well as provide for localization. So it might end up doing something like this

```
[Localized]
[Branded]
public string Greeting { get; set; }
```

Where [Localized] loads info from resource files, rather than pulling it in the view. The reason for this is that we don't wanna be passing around a ResourceManager throughout the session, and this would probably be much cleaner to manager once implemented.

I'm sure this is already going to make people cringe, but I'd like to explore it anyway. So I'm wondering if someone could point me in the right direction or offer any relevant experience with branding in MVC4.

UPDATE:

Ok, now that I followed some of what was answered below regarding the creation of an attribute, I have a better idea of what my question really is, so let me clarify:

I've created an attribute where I can decorate a property in the view model with the name of a property either stored as a resource or through some other means which will accomodate information branding. So the next step would be getting it into the view. So how do I pull that annotation into the view? I was thinking extension, so it would like this:

ViewModel

```
[Branded("greeting")] // this creates a string property called "Value" 
public string Greeting { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.BrandedFor(m => m.Greeting) //this should actually read from BrandedAttribute.Value on this property
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your question on how to create a custom attribute? If so, all you need to do it to inherit from the Attribute class.

```
using System;
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Struct)]
public class Person : Attribute
{
   public Person(string name) { this.name = name; }
   public int age;
   string name;
}
```

If what you want is an custom html helper then you can create something like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomLabel(this HtmlHelper html, string expression)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create("<label>" + expression +  + "</label>");
}
```

And use it like this:

```
 @Html.CustomLabel(m => m.Name);
```

Comment: Ok, fair enough, but how do I pull a property from the attribute in the view?

Comment: It seems like you are getting confused based on your update above. Do you want to create and attribute or an custom html helper?

Comment: I want to create an attribute that I can read from an html helper.

Comment: Regarding your update. The helper still doesn't show how to get the value out of the attribute on the decorated property. In other words, the Greeting property is marked with the Branded attribute. The branded attribute has a property called Value. The view is bound to a ViewModel that has the Greeting property. I need to get VALUE from that model, in the view -- as i show in my example.

Comment: take a look at this article: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=715. It looks like what is being described is what you are trying to accomplish